# NodeJS sum the object values in the array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have objects in the array.
one of these objects references another template.

I want the price of the data in the reference template to be multiplied by the number in the array, and I want the result to be written to the total.

```
const debt = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  medicine: [{

    data: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Medicine',
    },
    quantity: {
      type: Number,
      default: 1
    }
  }],
  total: {
    type: Schema.Types.Decimal128,
    default: 0,
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
```

```
const medicine = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
  },
  price: {
    type: Schema.Types.Decimal128,
    required: true,
  },
  medicineType: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
```

When we create data from the two templates above, the result is as follows.

```
{
  name: 'John Doe',
  no: '87102621880',
  status: 'debtor',
  note: 'not paid',
  medicine: [
    { data: '624e0b9533533f3a31e3dc73', quantity: 2 },
    { data: '624e0b3633533f3a31e3dc6a', quantity: 3 }
  ],
  total: 0
}
```

In the above result, the total value is zero, but I want it like this.

```
total = data.price * medicine.quantity
```

I want to do this operation inside the pre method, is it possible or is there another way?

I hope I have been able to explain, if there is more than one value in the medicine array, all of them `(data.price * medicine.quantity)` should do the same and transfer them to the total value.

Comment: use `Array.prototype.reduce()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: I couldn't do it :(

Comment: I provided an answer

Comment: Where did you get this from?
University project...

Answer (score -1):

You can define mongoose middleware to run pre/post some actions in the schema.

```
debtSchema.post('find',(results)=>{//do whatever you want here, it'll run every time you're querying by the 'find' method and you have access to the results})
```

Here's link to the [official docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)

Comment: in your answer the total stays 0, you just log the number to the console. you just can't reduce the array before it exist... so you can use a middleware to do so

Comment: obviously he will set the total to the value from `console.log` but I'm not here to write the application for him but help with his problem

Comment: question is `sum the object values in the array` how does saying that "you can do it after post" help with resolving the issue? I will tell you more you can do it after looping over the data 60 times and after doing `sleep` for 10 minutes but how does that help resolving the issue?

Comment: if you will implement the reduct in the middleware you will get the results into the total property. that's all. I don't think the question was how to sum an array, but how to sum in mongoose

Answer (score -1):

use `Array.prototype.reduce()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

```js
const a = {
  name: 'John Doe',
  no: '87102621880',
  status: 'debtor',
  note: 'not paid',
  price: 5,
  medicine: [
    { data: '624e0b9533533f3a31e3dc73', quantity: 2, price: 5 },
    { data: '624e0b9533533f3a31e3dc73', quantity: 1, price: 3 },
    { data: '624e0b3633533f3a31e3dc6a', quantity: 3, price: 6 },
  ],
  total: 0,
}

console.log(
  a.medicine.reduce(
    (previousValue, currentValue) =>
      previousValue + currentValue.quantity * currentValue.price,
    0,
  ),
)

// if price is in different object

console.log(
  a.medicine.reduce(
    (previousValue, currentValue) =>
      previousValue + currentValue.quantity * a.price,
    0,
  ),
)

// or just get count and then multiply by price
console.log(
  a.medicine.reduce(
    (previousValue, currentValue) =>
      previousValue + currentValue.quantity,
    0,
  ) * a.price,
)
```

Edit: eddited mistake in snipper where it was adding instead of multiplying

Comment: the total stays 0, you just log the number to the console. you just can't reduce the array before it exist... so you can use a middleware to do so

Comment: It works but it works wrong I guess NaN is throwing value.

Comment: what do you mean it works wrong? I assumed that price is included in the data because there was no price in your original post

Comment: Price information is included, price information needs to be accessed from data, I think you misunderstood the subject.

Comment: @FatihGumus I've updated the answer is it correct now?

Comment: It sends err, I need to reach price from data object data object is referenced from another field so I need to access it first and I don't know that.

Comment: @FatihGumus I don't know how price relates to medicine array. If you would provide more detailed example or explanation then I could help more

Comment: If you look at the schema in the subject, you can actually understand.
We referenced the medicine schema in the debt schema.

  the number of drugs: debt->medicine->quantity.
drug price : debt->medicine->data->price.
Price is actually present in the main medicine schema, which you can look at from above and see.